# Corona: "build for" menu doesn't include iPhone

Tags: iphone, build, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to test if I can put some apps I made on my phone somehow, but in corona I can only build for Android, Kindle and Nook, not for iPhone. Does anyone know why that option is not there?

Running on Windows 7 with Java 7 JDK.

Comment: Corona?  What application are you using to build the apps?  Is this from Dreamweaver?  Or are you just using the command line?

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what nycynik said RE needing Xcode to build for iOS, you can use macincloud.com with Corona. Lots of our developers who are PC users do this for their iOS apps. (I felt that was worth mentioning as while the phonegap article is good it wont really help you when using the Corona SDK.)

Answer (score -1):

You can only build for iOS using apple xcode.  The command line will not build for apple on windows.

To get around this, you could compile in the cloud, check out this link:

http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/03/15/corona-developers-rent-a-mac-in-the-cloud/

Comment: PhoneGap is a completely different SDK. The reason they are not seeing the "Build for iOS" menu option is because they are running on Windows. They just need to install the Corona SDK on their Mac and then the option will be present.